# Construct an Enum dynamically from a list, that is auto-completable by Visual Studio Code

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, enums, static-analysis

I am trying to dynamically build an `Enum` directly from a list of strings. I found a way, but it doesn’t really look clean and most importantly, VisualCode's autocompletion does not work.

```
from enum import Enum, auto

conf = ["x", "y"]
E = Enum("E", " ".join(conf))
```

[image: Enum without autocomplete.]

Is there a better way to do that? One that would allow my IDE to understand it directly as if I had written:

```
class A(Enum):
    x = auto()
    y = auto()
```

[image: Enum with autocomplete.]

Why am I not directly writing it as an enum? Actually, the conf is a big `dict`, and I’m extracting only some fields (with `glom`) that I want to make an `Enum` out of.

I suspect that what I want to achieve is unfeasible, it looks like `dict` objects are not parsed during static analysis, but many thanks if anyone has an idea!

Note: I tried it both with `jedi` and the `Microsoft python language server`.

Comment: You can clean up your `Enum` creation a little bit:  `E = Enum("E", conf)` -- no need to turn it into a string.

Comment: Never realized that! Thanks